# Best way to go from 5V to .95V to power an FPGA at max 15A

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-design, power-electronics, fpga

I need to power the core voltage on an FPGA from a 5 volt supply with a lot of constraints.

This is a rad hard environment so many components are ruled out. I'm only able to find a SMPS that will go down to 1 V (PE99155).

The 5 V is coming from a homemade SMPS that I'm building; I could go directly to 0.95 V with this, but I'd rather not have to rely on that SMPS for regulation since it's homemade.

I was thinking of using a LDO with external pass transistor to shunt more current. Would that provide good regulation from 5 V?

Are there any simpler/other ways to do this?

Comment: Can you get an FPGA that works at 1 V?

Comment: Cant change the fpga

Comment: 5 V --> 0.95 V @ 15 A with a linear regulator is 60.75 W.  Even if it's for short periods, do you want to deal with that much dissipation?  A 5 V to 0.95 V synchronous buck is relatively easy, pick a suitable converter or controller and go with that, or modify your 5 V converter to output 0.95 V.  Be careful of the transient response requirements though.

Comment: There are no PWM controllers i can use for a SMPS due to radiation requirements. I could modify my buck converter to go down to .95V but id rather not have to do that cause its homemade. And like i said there's only one buck converter ive found that will work but will only go to 1V, maybe there are more though

Comment: Is this for a Cubesat?

Comment: no but its going to space

Comment: You trust your homemade buck to reliably output 5 V but not 0.95 V? You have EMI margins for that but not a commercial buck module?

Comment: I dont trust it much at all, which is why id rather go through an ldo or something, I havent even considered EMI. There are no commercial modules that will work with my input voltages but maybe theres one that would go from 5 to .95V that i could find

Comment: What controller are you using in your 5 volt design that is rad hardened?

Comment: Its a homemade design thats a discrete component buck converter. I generate my own pwm signal and triangle wave and close the loop with a error amplifier. Im using a half bridge module to drive the inductor/capacitor.

Comment: You should need more than one rail and probably power sequencing. If your application is power constrained an LDO will consume a lot of power

Comment: Have you considered modules? Pretty sure outfits like Vicor will have something rad hard that will work, maybe you can go direct from the bus and reduce losses.

Comment: LT makes buck converter chips that work down to 0.4 V, I believe. They're expensive, because it's LT, but they might be worth a look.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at there space rated products page but none of them will work. It looks like they only have 1 buck converter space rated. Price doesnt matter :)

Comment: TI and other vendors have space/rad-hard PWM controllers.  Some targeted at isolated topologies but could be used for a non-isolated buck too.  One example: https://www.ti.com/product/TPS7H5007-SEP

Comment: Most (all?) rad hard controllers wont work because the transistor technology is not adequate. At least according to are radiation team.

Comment: So the "transistor technology" in PWM controllers isn't OK, but the high-density digital process used in FPGAs is? That probably leaves out modules too, because they all use PWM controllers internally.  So assuming you don't want to dissipate the extra 60 W in an LDO, which seems like a non-starter, especially in space, you have to modify your 5 V converter for 0.95 V output, or roll your own discrete 5 V to 0.95 V converter.  I have seen digital PWM controllers build on FPGAs, so if a 5V FPGA or microcontroller is OK you could use that.

Comment: No, the fpga technology isnt rad hard enough either but the final design will be an asic, we're just doing all the design work for that now

Comment: @JamesScholl But if the FPGA won't be there in the end because it's not rad hard enough isn't there little point to your current efforts of designing really low voltage, really high current rad-hard regulator for the FPGA? Because in the end a rad hard ASIC is going to be there, and that ASIC can be designed with voltage requirements that a rad hard SMPS can achieve. The ASIC should also be much lower current than the FPGA. Couldn't the non-rad hard SMPS module be blocked together with the FPGA? And be fed by the rad-hard regulator the ASIC will ultimately use?

Comment: In the interest of changing as little as possible it makes sense to adopt a rad-hard buck solution even at the FPGA stage. The thing to check is, what will your core voltage be for the ASIC, and can the buck be set up to accommodate that? 1V to 0.95 isn't a big deal, but 1V to 0.8 might be a problem.

Comment: @JamesScholl What is the intended lifetime of the device? Maybe rad-hard is more of a nice-to-have than a necessity, or is it going through the Van Allen radiation belts?

Comment: @James SchollMaybe this warrants a separate question but what are your rad requirements?  As you probably know, there's a lot more to it than just TID.  Will your system be operating continuously, or is is turned off or powered down periodically?  What are the consequences of an SEU (loss of a small amount of data?  Loss of the mission?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the Renesas [Rad Hard Switching Regulators](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/space-harsh-environment/rad-hard-hermetic/rad-hard-power/rad-hard-switching-regulators?field-output-current-max-rail-1-=15%2C22) which has been filtered to select regulators which can supply a maximum of 15 A there are the following which might meet the requirements:

- [ISL70002SEH](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/space-harsh-environment/rad-hard-hermetic/rad-hard-power/rad-hard-switching-regulators/isl70002seh-radiation-hardened-and-see-hardened-22a-synchronous-buck-regulator-current-sharing)
- [ISL73002SEH](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/products/space-harsh-environment/rad-hard-hermetic/rad-hard-power/rad-hard-switching-regulators/isl73002seh-radiation-hardened-and-see-hardened-22a-synchronous-buck-regulator-current-sharing)

For both:

- Input voltage range 3 V to 6.2 V
- Output voltage range 0.6 V to 4.675 V
- Maximum output current 22 A
- Product Status is reported as *Active*
- Full military temperature range operation (-55 °C to +125 °C)
- The description starts with `is a radiation hardened and SEE hardened high-efficiency monolithic, synchronous buck regulator with integrated MOSFETs`

The *Radiation environment* is different:

1. For the ISL70002SEH:

   - HDR (50-300rad(Si)/s): 100krad(Si)
   - LDR (0.01rad(Si)/s): 50krad(Si)
2. For the ISL73002SEH:

   - LDR (0.01rad(Si)/s): 50krad(Si)

The *SEE hardness* is the same for both:

- SEL and SEB LET<sub>TH</sub> 86.4MeV/mg/cm<sup>2</sup>
- SEFI LET<sub>TH</sub> 43MeV/mg/cm<sup>2</sup>
- SET LET<sub>TH</sub> 86.4MeV/mg/cm<sup>2</sup>

The question contains `This is a rad hard environment` without specifying any figures for the radiation dose so I'm not sure if the above will meet the requirement. If the above don't meet the requirement, can the question be edited to provide more information about the radiation environment?

Comment: I dont want to mention the exact rad requirements but im going to see if that 6.2 to 3V regulator is good with the radiation team. Even though its TID is 100krad it may be good beyond that. thanks

Comment: Well if your application is such that the exact radiation requirement cannot be revealed, then you probably shouldn't be looking for design advice on a public forum.

Comment: And note that we have used the SL70002 that Chester Gillon mentioned extensively on some programs that required rad tolerance, not hardness.  So it's probably a good starting point for your use.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what your 5 V current requirement is, apart from your notional concept of generating the 0.95 V 15 A supply from the 5 V supply.

But I think you should generate both your 5 V and 0.95 V outputs from your SMPS.  We've done designs where we created 1.5 V @ 200 A and 2 V @ 10 amps from the same SMPS, using different secondary windings of the transformer for the two voltages.

To a large extent whether this works for you or not depends on such things as the variablity in the current draws from the two supplies, what kind of tolerance you can stand on the outputs, etc.  In the example above, the draw on the 1.5 V could vary over a 10:1 range, IIRC, while the draw on the 2 V output was relatively constant, only varying about 10%-20%.

Comment: we probably dont have room for a transformer on the design

Comment: But you mentioned that your 5V is coming from an SMPS.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could coerce the PE99155 into making 0.95V by inserting a voltage divider between EAINP and VREF. Check with the Teledyne apps folks. (You did, they vetoed it.)

It's also possible to inject a current source into the feedback voltage divider to bring down the voltage. Here's an example of how that would work ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgBDEFBQ8YlCGwJBYASGLUqYePHCx4YBDVJ4alSGHIQZstgCVuKGuAx8xos1Gs1p1qjARsA7kZNa%20Pc1chsATvyCXty8IXxUGr6uwWh4YfFR8TEYQaG%20AZipfNjYnmnIcC5CufHCWVBFZaUigRWuVRZChHGNvgDmtbju4tho9mwAlp2Q3eUOCnAqpNMzs4RsuXGLtTRg5uIObAAe4MKmSFruGHHuggAUAGr6AKIAYgCU29xg9Lj0KMTZkHynIADCAFc-H4GAA7AAuAB0AM4AZQA9kCAMYMNhAA)):

[image]

You can fashion a current source from a fixed voltage and a resistor, if you have a known-good reference voltage, since we know that the feedback node would be always at 1V so the resistor current will also be fixed.

Example, if you have a precision 2.5V, a current source would look like this ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgBDEXG8DQ2nD4Di1KmHjxwseGAQ1SebMSVIIEyWwBKITCnCEqKGuMNRzJ8OaowEbAO66M+sGZ4GbbAE67Lxqu7+5rjwDtyQvGDE+oGWkGGxAWi+nj7YyUHYeLxB4qGOWTmWJkZxYSUpguL8UOVCYDU0rsK12IR4tM0NAjSEkTWeAB7gKPSuSChRBh2R+gAUWgwA5gCuADYcAC4A9l4AOgDOAGpaAKIAYgCU2pVBaB25FkbQSDZQL2zDGr6R2b7ksxAcwAygwAMbbAB2ABNDicLtcgA)):

[image]

You can use a precision LDO or a shunt regulator to create a clean voltage locally. Anything above about 2V should work. ADI offers the [REF43S Low Power 2.5 precision voltage reference](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ref43s.html#product-overview) as a space-qualified item for example.

That done, I don't see any other reason the switcher wouldn't work being jacked down to 0.95V, so long as the stepping ratio is ok (it's only 5:1 or so.)

If your final design ultimately uses a different regulator that also needs Vout < Vref, you can use the same technique.

Comment: i did ask and they said no. they said their reference is used elsewhere in the package

Comment: Injecting current into the feedback node doesn't change the reference, it just shifts the output voltage.

Answer (score 1):

A brief search on TI's website reveals a [handful](https://www.ti.com/power-management/non-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators/step-down-buck/products.html#1498=Space&) of space-rated buck controllers, several of which are capable of output voltages as low as 0.604 volts. In particular, the [TPS7H4003-SEP](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7h4003-sep.pdf) and [TPS7H4001-SP](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps7h4001-sp.pdf) are capable of 18 A output, which seems like more than enough for your purposes. Both work from an input voltage of 3 to 7 volts.

These chips are not cheap, but they do everything you need in one convenient rad-hard package.

Comment: These are only spec'd to 50 kRad TID.  OP mentioned rad hard, which is generally to mean 300 kRad (I think) or better.  That's why I asked for more info on OP's rad requirements.

Comment: And even the data sheet says rad tolerant, not rad hard.

Comment: @SteveSh I wasn't aware these were different specifications; I thought they were synonyms. I work on test equipment; rarely do I make anything that leaves the lab, let alone the atmosphere.

Answer (score 0):

Develop your own buck with a rad-hard fpga as a controller. You could use an external fet that is rad hard and devleop just the spec you need and save power. At an aerospace company I used to work for they did this all the time.

[image]

Source: https://www.eetimes.com/how-to-build-a-better-dc-dc-regulator-using-fpgas/

Comment: If you're powering the FPGA with this supply, might be a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem. The FPGA would need some kind of pilot supply to get it going first during configuration and startup. Not unsolvable, but just needs to be thought through carefully. Also, OP intends to use an ASIC for the actual craft, which of course could include PMIC functionality.

Comment: Different FPGA, two of them